# Open Source ASP.NET CMS

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, open-source

I'm looking for an Open Source ASP.NET CMS. !

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best open source .NET content management system (CMS)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243655/what-is-the-best-open-source-net-content-management-system-cms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[N2CMS](http://www.n2cms.com)** - built on/with NHibernate, Castle Project, jQuery, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC in version 2.0.

The source is on google code.

Comment: Source moved to https://github.com/n2cms

Answer (score 7):

There are actually several options to choose from here.

- http://umbraco.org/

They also have a Pro option if you are interested in that at a later date.

- http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

> DotNetNuke the most widely adopted Web Content Management Platform for building web sites and web applications on Microsoft .NET. Organizations use DotNetNuke to quickly develop and deploy interactive and dynamic web sites, intranets, extranets and web applications. The DotNetNuke platform is available in a free Community and subscription-based Professional, Elite  and Elite Premier Editions. DotNetNuke Corp. also operates Snowcovered.com where users purchase third party software modules and skins.

- http://www.rainbowportal.net/

> The Rainbow project is an open source initiative to build a comprehensive content management system using Microsoft's ASP.NET and C# technologies.

Comment: Thanks guys.
Do many web hosting host these frameworks?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

Answer (score 1):

Although not a true "CMS", more of an application framework that can do CMS functionality [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) is a great choice.

I use it for a lot of sites, it is fairly easy to work with and the learning curve isn't too  bad.